# GDAL tools for QGIS on OSX - what is the exact directory for gdal binaries?

Tags: python, gdal, osx

When I try to use the gdal raster tools, eg clipper, I get the message "The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program."  I have read the forums discussing this issue, and they seem to have solved it by using multiple paths for python and pymods, separated by "/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.7/Python/"

I am not sure of what this means, but I do know that setting the path to gdal binaries in the gdal tools settings to the path above does not work.

Is there a dumbed-down version of how to correctly set the paths in qgis?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The OS I am using is OSX 10.5 (Leopard), and I am using the 'GDAL complete' package.  I tried versions 1.7 and 1.8, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes! This is the exact point where I find myself (except I'm on OS X 10.6, QGIS 1.7, GDAL 1.8). Does anyone have an answer for us?

Answer (score 5):

the path is /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs which is a symbolic link to the latest version installed /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Programs

To use the commands in the console (shell):

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
gdalinfo ..
```

Or put this command in the bash_profile file

Comment: Thanks for providing an explicit and clear answer.  Glad to have you here!

Answer (score 0):

On my QGIS 1.7, here's the path:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/usr/bin
```